# Why are matrix lines not being displayed in this minimal document?

Tags: math-mode, matrices, document-classes

I'm using pdflatex to create PDF versions of LaTeX equations. My requirement is simply that an equation appear with a bit of whitespace around it, not on a "page".

Some example code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[paperwidth=\maxdimen,paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
$\displaystyle \left[\begin{array}{c|cc}
a & b & c \\ \hline
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{array} \right]$
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

I've had no issues save for the fact that the lines specified by the "|" and "\hline" don't appear. I assume this has something to do with the document class or environments I'm using since the lines appear properly in typical document classes such as "article".

The spacing between matrix elements also differs from the typical case, although this I can deal with.

Ideally I'd like the equation to appear just as it would as a display style equation in a typical document, but I'll settle for the lines showing up.

Any ideas on changes I can make to the code to remedy this issue?

I'd appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Why are you using the `minimal` document class? It should *never* be used for real production work. Please note that the often-repeated request for [Minimum Working Examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) does *not* entail using the`minimal` document class...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing to `article` document class works, as hoped. Perhaps `minimal` is *too* minimal. I have heard it advocated not to use the `minimal` document class, in general.

Also, the `geometry` package call appears to be superfluous, in the presence of the `preview` package, so I comment it out in my answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[paperwidth=\maxdimen,paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
$\displaystyle \left[\begin{array}{c|cc}
a & b & c \\ \hline
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{array} \right]$
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I originally got the code off this site and assumed the "minimal" class was needed to make it work.

Comment: @COTO Apparently, the `preview` package makes it possible.  It would also appear the `geometry` package call is superfluous, so I will remove it from my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The `minimal` class only defines the normal font. Several parameters are only initialized in the format and it's the duty of the class to set them.

In particular, `minimal` doesn't set `\arrayrulewidth`. Here's an excerpt from `article.cls` (line numbers are for reference)

```
442 \setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
443 \setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
444 \setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
445 \setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}
446 \setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}
447 \skip\@mpfootins = \skip\footins
448 \setlength\fboxsep{3\p@}
449 \setlength\fboxrule{.4\p@}
```

The standard reference for this is [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

You could use the `minimal` class, just add

```
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

to the preamble. But it's easier using `article` and doing `\pagestyle{empty}`. Even better

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle \left[\begin{array}{c|cc}
a & b & c \\ \hline
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{array} \right]$

\end{document}
```

[image]